# Call external Script from integrated Python-Interpreter

Tags: python, external, interpreter, laravel-artisan

I'm struggling with a simple Python Script, which i want to call from within another programm written in Python also. As i'm very new to Python, i don't know, how to solve this.

I'm using [Artisan](https://github.com/artisan-roaster-scope/artisan) which runs within an integrated interpreter. Artisan lets me define Buttons to trigger actions, such as calling an external script.
In my case, this external script should communicate to an Arduino via serial port. My external Script was originally written in Python3 but for testing purposes i also changed the code to Python2.
This is what it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
import serial

PORT = '/dev/tty.usbmodemFA131'

with serial.Serial(PORT, 9600) as arduino:
    time.sleep(2)
    arduino.write(sys.argv[1].encode('ASCII'))
    print(arduino.readline())
```

When i run this code from Terminal (i'm using MacOS 10.11.5), it works just like expected.

When i call it from within Artisan, Python crashes, showing the following notifications:

> Last login: Wed Jul 13 07:21:46 on ttys000 Philipps-Air:~ philipp$
>   /Applications/Artisan.app/Contents/MacOS/Artisan ; exit; Jul 13
>   07:22:20  Artisan[40170] :
>   /Applications/Artisan.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273:
>   UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This
>   may take a moment. Jul 13 07:22:57  Artisan[40170] : Fatal
>   Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec Jul
>   13 07:22:57  Artisan[40170] : ImportError: No module named
>   'encodings' Jul 13 07:22:57  Artisan[40170] :  Jul 13 07:22:57
>   Artisan[40170] : Current thread 0x00007fff73660000 (most
>   recent call first):

Next i tried to call another Another short script from within Artisan to call the above script:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['./arduino.py', sys.argv[1]])
```

Resulting in the same error :/

When changing code to Python2, notifications change, but the script won't execute either:

> Jul 13 18:56:15  Artisan[40956] : Traceback (most recent call
>   last): Jul 13 18:56:15  Artisan[40956] :   File
>   "/Users/philipp/arduino.py", line 5, in  Jul 13 18:56:15 
>   Artisan[40956] :     import serial Jul 13 18:56:15 
>   Artisan[40956] :   File "serial/**init**.pyo", line 13, in
>    Jul 13 18:56:15  Artisan[40956] :   File
>   "serial/serialutil.pyo", line 10, in  Jul 13 18:56:15 
>   Artisan[40956] :   File "io.pyo", line 51, in  Jul 13
>   18:56:15  Artisan[40956] : ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Applications/Artisan.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder Jul 13
>   18:56:15  Artisan[40956] :   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Artisan.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
>   Jul 13 18:56:15  Artisan[40956] :   Expected in: flat
>   namespace Jul 13 18:56:15  Artisan[40956] :  in
>   /Applications/Artisan.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so

I tried **hash -r python** but this didn't change a thing.

What do i have to do, in order to get my script interpreted by my EXTERNAL Python (prefferably Python3) interpreter instead of using the Artisan-integrated one?

All scripts were made executable and the necessary libs were both installed into Python3 und Python2, which came with MacOS.

Thank you very much for your help!

Philipp